# VHDL Counter not Working

Tags: fpga, pwm, vhdl, counter

I have code below for a counter that sets an output bit high or low depending on the count value being compared with a reference value. It is used to generate a PWM signal.

During simulation, the PWM_Output bit is always high as I think the Count_Value signal in never incremented inside the if statement.

Any ideas as to why this PWM_Output bit is not toggling? (Sorry, I am unsure how to get the code in one snippet, maybe someone who knows how will edit the question).

Below is the code:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use work.Data_Sizes_Package.all;

entity PWM_Counter_and_Comparator is

    Generic
    (
        Max_Counter_Value : integer := 20
    );

    Port
    (
        PWM_Comparison_Value    : in std_logic_vector(27 downto 0);
        Clock                   : in std_logic;
        Run_Reset               : in std_logic;
        PWM_Output              : out std_logic
    );

end PWM_Counter_and_Comparator;

architecture Behavioral of PWM_Counter_and_Comparator is

    signal PWM_Comparison_Value_int : integer range 0 to Max_Counter_Value;
    signal Count_Value : integer range 0 to Max_Counter_Value;

begin

    PWM_Comparison_Value_int <= conv_integer(unsigned(PWM_Comparison_Value));

    process(Clock, Run_Reset)
    begin

        if Run_Reset = '0' then
            Count_Value <= 0;

            if Count_Value = Max_Counter_Value then
                Count_Value <= 0;

                if (Run_Reset = '1') and (Count_Value < PWM_Comparison_Value_int) then
                    Count_Value <= Count_Value + 1;
                end if;

            end if;

        end if;

    end process;

    process(Clock , Run_Reset)

    begin

        if (Count_Value < PWM_Comparison_Value_int) and (Run_Reset = '1') then
            PWM_Output <= '1';
        else
            PWM_Output <= '0';
        end if;

    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Where is your clock event statement inside the processes?(or rising edge)

Comment: Also are you sure: you want to write a nested if structure? Check where to write end if of your conditions.

Comment: @BerkerIşık Does the clock have to be in the processes? I use the clock in the sensitivity list to run the process? Maybe I'm misunderstanding how processes work?

Comment: You can write elsif after your reset condition. If reset doesnt occur, your counter count up until your period.

Comment: Your code enters last 2 blocks only first condition if true. This means reset state.

Comment: @BerkerIşık Ah of course yeah. They are nested. I will try to fix my code tomorrow and let you know the result. Thanks

Comment: İ'm mobile now. I cant write any code now. But look this link please. You can use sync process with clock, you dont need reset in the sensivity list. https://vhdlwhiz.com/clocked-process/

Comment: Hmm, the code looks like C/C++ style. Where's the clock? Counters are sequential circuits. Sequential circuits have clocks. You gotta strengthen your fundamentals in RTL design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` statements are nested, so if `Run_Reset = '1'`, the entire process is skipped, and if `Run_Reset = '0'`, the counter is reset and the increment code is skipped. The counter can never take on any other value than zero.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I see now what my mistake is. So if you want 3 separate (non-nested) if statements within a process, does the (end if;) have to be before the next if statement is written?

Comment: @David777, yes, or in your case since all of them assign to the same signal and only the last assignment before the `wait` statement (implicit in the sensitivity list) is executed, you want to use `elsif`.

Comment: Ah ok, but you mention 'wait' statement? Is this something that happens within a process body?

Comment: @David777, if a process has a sensitivity list, the language pretends that the process body has a loop around it, that waits until a signal in the sensitivity list has an event. I.e. `process(reset, clk) is begin ... end process;` is equivalent to `process is begin loop wait until reset'event or clk'event; ... end loop; end process;`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the standard libraries [`numeric_std`](https://opensource.ieee.org/vasg/Packages/-/blob/master/ieee/numeric_std.vhdl) and [`numeric_std_unsigned`](https://opensource.ieee.org/vasg/Packages/blob/master/ieee/numeric_std_unsigned.vhdl) instead of `std_logic_arith` and `std_logic_unsigned`.

The below example is the standard form for a clocked process with an asynchronous reset for VHDL-2008. I'm not sure what PWM comparator logic you require, so I'll let you decide what to put:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
--use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;  -- Standard library.
--use work.Data_Sizes_Package.all;

entity PWM_Counter_and_Comparator is

    Generic
    (
        Max_Counter_Value : integer := 20
    );

    Port
    (
        PWM_Comparison_Value    : in std_logic_vector(27 downto 0);
        Clock                   : in std_logic;
        Reset                   : in std_logic;
        PWM_Output              : out std_logic
    );

end PWM_Counter_and_Comparator;

architecture Behavioral of PWM_Counter_and_Comparator is

    signal Count_Value : integer range 0 to Max_Counter_Value;

begin

    process(all)  -- For VHDL-2008, use all to replace the sensitivity list.
    begin

        if Reset then  -- Asynchronous reset condition.

            Count_Value <= 0;
            PWM_Output <= '0';

        elsif rising_edge(Clock) then  -- Synchronous logic

            if Count_Value = Max_Counter_Value then
                Count_Value <= 0;
                PWM_Output <= not PWM_Output;  -- Outputs are readable in VHDL-2008.
                                               -- Toggles the output every time Count_Value equals Max_Counter_Value.
                                               -- I'm not sure if this was your intent, so I'll leave it up to you to decide.
            else
                Count_Value <= Count_Value + 1;
            end if;

        end if;

    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the PWM_Comparison_Value is supposed to control the PWM wave uptime.

Comment: Thanks tim. Yeah this was not my intent but I get the point. I'll change to suit my own logic. What do you mean by 'all' in the process sensitivity list? Does this include all inputs that are defined in the entity?

Comment: @David777, `all` means all of the signals that are read in the `process`. Historically, sensitivity lists used to cause lots of bugs due to simulator-synthesis mismatches, but that's now a thing of the past. When `all` is used, modern simulators read through the `process` to find out which signals are being read, then infer the sensitivity list from that. Antiquated simulators would rely on the sensitivity list whereas synthesisers rely on what's in the `process` leading to a mismatch if there is a mistake in the sensitivity list that doesn't match what is in the `process`.